# Table view from array index out of range

Tags: ios, arrays, uitableview

I'm using an array to read data from a database, Currently I have 8 items in the array. I am trying to make a table where I have a section header. Currently I have 4 sections and I have set that properly and it works. It also works running the first time but when I try to scroll back I get an index out of range. I am using myarray[myindex] to set the cell data for each item and that is not working.

It seems that I need to break up my data into 4 sections that contains only the data for each section to let the table view control it properly. The data can contain any number of sections.

Is there a better way to do this?

I have attached a pic to describe the problem.

[image: Screen shot of table]

Thanks

Adding code on request.

```
  override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    print("Returning Sections - > \(sections)")
    return sections //seems to work
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    print("Return number of rows in section -> \(noRowsInSection[section])")
    return noRowsInSection[section] // seems to work
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return sectionHeader[section] // seems to work
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    // Format for section Headers
    let header:UITableViewHeaderFooterView = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView
    header.textLabel!.textColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    UIColor.blueColor()
    header.textLabel!.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(12)
    header.textLabel!.frame = header.frame
    header.textLabel!.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Right
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("OurCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! OurTableViewCell
    print("myindex - > \(myindex) row -> \(indexPath.row)")
    cell.OurCellLabel.text = MyHouses[myindex].getAddressDetails()        // End configure houses.cell
    //cell.OurCellLabel.text = MyHouses[indexPath.row].getAddressDetails()        // End configure houses.cell
    myindex++ // PROBLEM HERE - GOES OUT OF RANGE
    return cell
}
```

Here I am getting data from the sqlite DB

```
func GetListOfHousesFromDB() {
    let docsDir = dirPaths[0]
    let databasePath = docsDir.stringByAppendingString("/newdb.db")
    if fileMgr.fileExistsAtPath(databasePath as String) {
        let houseDB = FMDatabase(path: databasePath as String)
        if houseDB.open() {
            var noRows: Int = 0
            var sql = "select count(Address) as cnt from Houses" // Define Query
            houseDB.executeStatements(sql) // Execute Query
            let results:FMResultSet? = houseDB.executeQuery(sql,withArgumentsInArray: nil) //Get results from Query
            if results?.next() == true {
                let cnt = (results?.stringForColumn("cnt"))! // Retrieve number of rows from DB
                noRows = Int(cnt)!
            }
            var i = 0
            sql = "SELECT Address, Street, City, State, Zip from Houses ORDER BY State, City, Street, Address" // Define Query
            houseDB.executeStatements(sql) // Execute Query
            let results2:FMResultSet? = houseDB.executeQuery(sql,withArgumentsInArray: nil) // Get results from Query
            while results2?.next() == true {
                MyHouses.append(newhouse())
                MyHouses[i].address = (results2?.stringForColumn("Address"))!
                MyHouses[i].street = (results2?.stringForColumn("Street"))!
                MyHouses[i].city = (results2?.stringForColumn("City"))!
                MyHouses[i].state = (results2?.stringForColumn("State"))!
                MyHouses[i].zip = (results2?.stringForColumn("Zip"))!
                print("Address -> \(i) \(MyHouses[i].getAddressDetails())")
                i++
            }
        }
        houseDB.close()
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us some relevant code, especially the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, `numberOfRowsInSection` and `numberOfSectionsInTableview` methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34163054/define-object-with-multidimensional-properties/34163684#34163684), what you need is an updated `House` model and updated data structure for handling data for your table view.

> House - Model class

```
struct House {
    var address: String
    var street: String
    var city: String
    var state: String
    var zip: String

    func getAddressDetails() -> String {
        return "\(address) \(street) \(city) \(state) \(zip)"
    }

    func getCityState() -> String {
        return "\(city) - \(state)"
    }
}
```

> Helper Class for loading data

```
class HouseDataHelper {

    private static let _sharedInstance = HouseDataHelper()
    var myHouses: Dictionary<String, [House]> = [:]

    private init() {
        loadHouseData()
    }

    static func sharedInstance() -> HouseDataHelper {
        return _sharedInstance
    }

    private func loadHouseData() {
        var houses = [House]()

        //Populating your actual values here. GetListOfHousesFromDB()

        //Loading dummy data for testing
        var sectionHeader = ""
        for i in 0...4 {
            sectionHeader = "Header \(i)"
            houses += [House(address: "Address1", street: "Street1", city: "City1", state: "State1", zip: "Zip1")]
            houses += [House(address: "Address2", street: "Street2", city: "City2", state: "State2", zip: "Zip2")]
            houses += [House(address: "Address3", street: "Street3", city: "City3", state: "State3", zip: "Zip3")]
            houses += [House(address: "Address4", street: "Street4", city: "City4", state: "State4", zip: "Zip4")]
            houses += [House(address: "Address5", street: "Street5", city: "City5", state: "State5", zip: "Zip5")]

            myHouses.updateValue(houses, forKey: sectionHeader)
            houses = []
        }
    }
}
```

> Table View Controller

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var houses = HouseDataHelper.sharedInstance().myHouses
    var sectionHeaders: [String] = []

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        sectionHeaders = Array(houses.keys.sort())
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return houses.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if let rows = houses[sectionHeaders[section]] {
            return rows.count
        }

        return 0
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return sectionHeaders[section]
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        //Populate cells based on "houses"
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll give this a try, a few things I don't really understand but we'll see if I can get it working..... thanks!

Comment: I ended up using a multi-dimensional array[section][row]. It's working.