# Define object with multidimensional properties

Tags: ios, arrays, multidimensional-array, swift2

PROBLEM:
What I'm looking for is to display this info in a table so I think I need:

MyHouses1[section][row].getAddressDetails()

How do I properly define MyHouses1?

```
    import UIKit

class House {
    var address = "Address"
    var street = "Street"
    var city = "City"
    var state = "State"
    var zip = "Zip"

    func getAddressDetails() -> String {
        return "\(address) \(street) \(city) \(state) \(zip)"
        //return "\(address) \(street)"
    }
    func getCityState() -> String {
        return "\(city) - \(state)"
    }
}

class newhouse: House {
    var lighting = "crappy"
    var plumbing = "sucks"
    var heating = "heats good"
    var cooling = "cools good"
    var repairs = "needs alot of repairs"

    func getFixtureDetails() -> String {
        return "\(lighting) \(plumbing) \(heating) \(cooling)"
    }
}

// THIS WORKS
var MyHouses: [newhouse] = [] 
MyHouses.append(newhouse())  
MyHouses[0].address = "test" 
MyHouses[0].getAddressDetails() 


// THIS DOESN'T WORK 

var MyHouses1: [[newhouse]] = [] // No Error Yet
MyHouses1.append // Getting an error here, not sure how to append
```

Details: in order to post the website wants me to add more details.....so here I am adding more details lol

Comment: newhouse is a class that inherits from House? And you set the properties of newhouse in the actual class? I don't understand what you're trying to do here... Could you perhaps explain what you're trying to do and how houses relate to eachother?

Comment: Here is another post about the problem that I think explains it. I am trying to do this to fix the problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34139728/table-view-from-array-index-out-of-range

Comment: Ok, how is this question different than your other question then? Isn't this a duplicate post?

Comment: It's what I'm working on, this is a simpler version of my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this..

```
var MyHouses1: [[newhouse]] = []// No Error Yet
var houses = [newhouse]() //Initialize your `newhouse` array here

for i in 0...4 {
    houses += [newhouse()]
}

MyHouses1 += [houses] 

print("\(MyHouses1[0][0].city)") // will print "City"
```

Comment: MyHouses1[0][0].address = "test" gives an error index out of range

Comment: We have only declared the `houses` array in `var houses = [newhouse]()` and I was expecting you to do the initialization to validate the code :( . The code is updated now, please check.